# Issue with storing session in memcache on linux

Tags: php, linux, session, memcached

Can you explain this problem: I'm using memcache to store session for my php web app. Every necessary configuration is set up. But the session just be saved on current page, after change to other its value had gone away.

This is my config for storing session in memcache: 
session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path = "tcp:127.0.0.1:11211"

I'm thinking about time life of memcache.
Anybody know how to resolve this problem, please give me an advice. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `session.save_path`to `tcp://localhost:11211/` (you forgot those important two slashes)